# fetch API not returning response

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

```
   async function getQuote() {
  console.log("heya");

  const url = "/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1";

  const response = await fetch(url);

  console.log(response);
  return await response.json();

  // console.log("hello", quote);
}

getQuote().then(result => {
  console.log("here");
  console.log(result.shift());
});
```

This is my code. Why isnt response returning something?
    Link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJYGNJ?editors=1012

Comment: Use `.catch(console.error)` and you'll see a *"Failed to fetch"* message. No wonder given that the URL doesn't exist on codepen.

Comment: @Bergi thanks a lot for pointing it out!   I was trying to recreate the following using fetch API , async and wait : [link](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/MwaXpq?editors=1010).  How do I achieve it?

Comment: Well, how about supplying the same full url, including the domain, then?

Comment: @Bergi *facepalm!! thanks again!